# "Javascript not available on browser" when Flask server receives an HTML Response from API

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I spun up a local Flask server in order to create a Web UI for managing some of my network devices. When my networking device replies to my Flask server to ask for sign-in credentials, I receive this response (edited for security reasons):

**Web-Browser: Google Chrome**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>

<body class="vega signin-body">
  <div id="root"></div>

<noscript>
  <div class="signin-page">
    <div class="panels">
      <div class="panel signin">
        <h2 class="important">Error: JavaScript not available</h2>
        <div class="panel-content corner-bottom">
          <p>
            This web interface requires a modern browser with JavaScript
            enabled.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</noscript>
  <script src="/static/vega-app-70224f965ab5fa468768.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/vega-vendor.bundle-70224f965ab5fa468768.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My Code: I know that all of my Utils functions work as intended, but my main issue is receiving the html/javascript response

**Server.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from utils import ngrokWebhook, indexHTML, book_room, book_meeting


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
        return indexHTML()

@app.route('/book', methods=["POST","GET"])
def book():
    meeting_title= request.form['meeting_title']
    time = request.form['time']
    ip_address = request.form['ip_address']
    test = book_room(ip_address, meeting_title, "2019-12-09T20:45:00", "2019-12-09T21:00:00")
    print(test)

    return test



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port=80, use_reloader=True, debug=True)
```

**Utils.py:**

```
def getStatus(url, payload,  query):
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, params=query, verify = False)

    return response.text

def book_room(url, meeting_title, start_time, end_time):
    response = getStatus(
        url,
        book_meeting(meeting_title,start_time, end_time, ""),
        "bookingsputxml")

    return response
```

How can I respond to the Authentication HTML response that I receive?

Comment: Do you have javascript enabled on your clients web browser?

Comment: You've already identified the problem, no? I'm not sure what we're supposed to be answering

Comment: *I receive this response* - you're making the request from server code, right? Therefore the thing that is making the request **isn't** a browser with javascript

Comment: @Jaromanda X Oh that makes complete sense. Is there a way for me to make the request from the server, or would I have to go through a browser?